# Laravel 5.8 VM2666:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5

I want the user to register using ajax and when everything goes right I want to return JSON response {'success', 'thank you'} now in order to do that in register controller i overwrite the register method as follow:

```
 public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));
        if($request->ajax()){
            return response()->json(["success", "thank you"], '200');
        }
        $this->guard()->login($user);
        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

but in Javascript/JQuery I get the following:

```
VM2666:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success ((index):2003)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at z (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
success @ (index):2003
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
z @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:4
load (async)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ (index):1997
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

what is wrong? how to fix it please?

here is my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '/register',
            data: data,
            // dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
            console.log(data[0]);
        }
         error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
})
```

Comment: Are you sure that the error is due to this line: `return response()->json(["success", "thank you"], '200');`?

Comment: @dparoli no I am not sure, but I highly suspect it is, since as I understand from googling the error is that this error is due not correctly formatted json

Comment: My suspect is that the code runs till the last return statement, try to return response()->json(["success", "thank you"], '200'); on every request without any condition and see if the error is gone.

Comment: @dparoli I tried what you said, but the error is the same

Comment: try `response()->json(["success" => "thank you"], '200');` note the `=>` instead `,` to assign the value to the key `"success"`